# returning multiple results set from union all query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have got this SP to check whether  the user is having any licenses that are stored in different tables..

I am getting results into dataset and from that dataset i am getting individual results with the count and if the count greater than zero then that user is having licenses.

This is the SP

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UserCheck]
(
@activatedBy varchar(30),
@brand varchar(20)
)
AS 
BEGIN 
   DECLARE @acctId as BIGINT
   SELECT @acctId = pk_acct_id from accounts with(nolock) where email = @activatedBy  and  brand = @brand

 IF LEN(@acctId) > 1
  BEGIN
     SELECT count(*) from dbo.links with(nolock) where one = @acctId
   union all 
     SELECT COUNT(*)FROM waveactivationinfo with(nolock) where Activated_by = @acctId    
   union all
      SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ABCActivationInfo with(nolock) WHERE Activated_by = @acctId
   union all
      SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CSE_ActivationInfo with(nolock) WHERE activated_by = @acctId
   union all
       SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Connect_ActivationInfo  with(nolock) WHERE activated_by = @acctId
   union all
       SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LicActivationInfo with(nolock) WHERE Activated_by = @acctId
   END 
END
GO
```

and then in DAL I am catching that results into dataset like this

```
    public DataSet UserCheck(string strEmailID, string strBrand)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        List<SqlParameter> ParaList = new List<SqlParameter>();
        ParaList.Add(new SqlParameter("@activatedBy", strEmailID));
        ParaList.Add(new SqlParameter("@brand", strBrand));
        ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString), CommandType.StoredProcedure, "UserCheck", Convert.ToInt32(Utility.GetConfigValue("Connection_TimeOut")), ParaList.ToArray());
        return ds;
    }
```

I am retrieving that dataset in code behind like this ...

```
 DataSet ds = userDeactivate.UserCheck(txtEmailID.Text.Trim(), brandType);


if (ds != null)
{
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        osCount = Int32.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString());
        waveCount=Int32.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[1].ItemArray[0].ToString());
        aCount = Int32.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[2].ItemArray[0].ToString());
        PassCount = Int32.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[3].ItemArray[0].ToString());
        quickCount = Int32.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[4].ItemArray[0].ToString());
        vmcCount = Int32.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[5].ItemArray[0].ToString());
    }
 }
```

I am thinking that this will not be a good way to check whether the user is having licenses .. Is there any alternatives for this

Is there any way to simply return the codes from SP for each result set .. if i want to get all counts from all queries do i need to modify any code in DAL ...

Comment: Use in your store procedure output parameter hasLicensce and change to SET has_license = EXISTS(SELECT 1 from dbo.links with(nolock) where one = acctId ...) and at end return output.

Comment: Do you need these multiple count(*) in your application or just simple INFO hasLicense or not?

Comment: I need individual counts also because i need to show to customer ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of getting these results back would be to use output parameters in your sp, something like ......

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UserCheck]
( @activatedBy      varchar(30)
 ,@brand            varchar(20)
 ,@Link_Count       INT         OUTPUT
 ,@Wave_Count       INT         OUTPUT
 ,@ABCA_Count       INT         OUTPUT
 ,@CSE_Count        INT         OUTPUT
 ,@Connection_Couny INT         OUTPUT
 ,@Lic_Count        INT         OUTPUT
)
AS 
BEGIN 
   DECLARE @acctId as BIGINT
   SELECT @acctId = pk_acct_id from accounts with(nolock) where email = @activatedBy  and  brand = @brand

 IF LEN(@acctId) > 1
  BEGIN
     SELECT @Link_Count = ISNULL(count(*), 0) from dbo.links with(nolock) where one = @acctId

     SELECT @Wave_Count = ISNULL(COUNT(*), 0) FROM waveactivationinfo with(nolock) where Activated_by = @acctId    

     SELECT @ABCA_Count = ISNULL(COUNT(*), 0)  FROM ABCActivationInfo with(nolock) WHERE Activated_by = @acctId

     SELECT @CSE_Count = ISNULL(COUNT(*), 0)  FROM CSE_ActivationInfo with(nolock) WHERE activated_by = @acctId

     SELECT @Connection_Couny = ISNULL(COUNT(*), 0)  FROM Connect_ActivationInfo  with(nolock) WHERE activated_by = @acctId

     SELECT @Lic_Count = ISNULL(COUNT(*), 0)  FROM LicActivationInfo with(nolock) WHERE Activated_by = @acctId
   END 
END
GO
```

### Call from C#

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Connection"]))
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[UserCheck]", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Link_Count", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Wave_Count", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ABCA_Count", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CSE_Count", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Connection_Couny", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Lic_Count", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@activatedBy", strEmailID));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@brand", strBrand));

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    int _linkCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@Link_Count"].Value);
    int _WaveCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@Wave_Count"].Value);
    // and so on......
}
```